# How to manage null return code on Cordova FileTransfer Error?

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, file-transfer

I'm trying to download a file with Cordova File Transfer but I'm getting a very confusing error message. This is my code:

```
let fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
let fileURL = encodeURI(cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'appname.apk');
let uri = encodeURI(Config.APP_DOWNLOAD_URL);

fileTransfer.download(
     uri,
     fileURL,
     (entry) => {
          console.log(entry);
     },
     (error) => {
          console.log(error);
     }
);
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
FileTransferError {code: null, source: null, target: null, http_status: null, body: null, exception: null}
```

Does anyone have an idea what is going wrong? Thanks in advance.